# Добавление кастомной локальной политики

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory

Можно ли как-то добавить свою локальную политику в `Параметры безопасности -> Локальные политики -> Назначение прав пользователей` свою политику, чтобы потом у себя в программе ее проверять и разрешать или запрещать пользователю некое действие?

Работать через административные шаблоны и проверять в программе ключ реестра пока не хочу. Интересует решение именно через локальные политики

Comment: А не проще завести группы безопасности на локальном компьютере или в домене и проверять, входит ли пользователь в необходимую группу? Они собственно для этого и нужны, а не только для раздачи прав на файлы.

Comment: Предложение интересное. Т.е. определять права просто из принадлежности группе? Тогда такой вопрос - я так понимаю, что группа однозначно определяется своим SID? SID генерируется в момент создания группы. Как мне в мою программу передать те сиды, которые нужно проверять? Т.е. передать то можно через административные шаблоны, но как эти сиды указать в самом шаблоне? Если оформите ответом - приму